# Count images in Folder using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to count the number of images a folder folder, but it produces this error :

`Could not find a part of the path 'c:\Content\slideshow\images\image\'.`

All of the images are in a folder in the project. Located a `Content/slideshow/images/image`

This is my code:

```
<%
  string dir = @"/Content/slideshow/images/image";
  string[] files;
  int numFiles;
  files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);
  numFiles = files.Length;
  Response.Write("num ber of images :" + numFiles);
%>
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  Seems like a perfectly fine question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Could not find a part of the path
>   'c:\Content\slideshow\images\image\'"

Means very simply that the folder does not exist. If you want to user a relative path you can do the following.

```
Server.MapPath("~/{RelativePathHere})
```

Edit : In response to your comment. You will need to loop through the file and check for file extension of each (Keeping your own count)

Comment: Great! it work Pino. But it count include "Thumbs.db", so can we take only the images. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to map the virtual path to physical path and then pass it to Directory.GetFiles method

Answer (score 1):

To call Directory.GetFiles() you need to pass the full path to the images directory.

```
string dirPath = @"~/Content/slideshow/images/image";
string dirFullPath = Server.MapPath(dirPath);
string[] files;
int numFiles;
files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
numFiles = files.Length;
Response.Write("number of images: " + numFiles);
```

Server.MapPath returns the entire physical file path associated to the dirPath virtual path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass this as a relative path `using Server.MapPath`
Then I would suggest using `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` instead of Directory.GetFiles and filter on the image types that you want, so you don't count non-image files. This will yield a `FileInfo[]`.

```
<%
  string dir = Server.MapPath(@"/Content/slideshow/images/image");
  FileInfo[] files;
  int numFiles;
  files = (new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir)).GetFiles("filePattern");
  numFiles = files.Length;
  Response.Write("num ber of images :" + numFiles);
%>
```

If you have multiple file types that you want to count the best way to do this is just to remove the pattern then filter the results.

```
  var extensions = new String[] {"jpg", "png", "gif"};
  files = (new System.IO.DirectInfo(dir)).GetFiles();

  foreach(var extension in extensions)
  {
    numFiles += files.AsEnumerable.Where(f => f.Extension.Equals(extension));
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int numberOfFiles ;
    string path = "C:/PIC";
    numberOfFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;
```

Check Now